# Adding a values columns in a text file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a text file with three columns as below

```
568234.099421 4497975.785405 0.000000
567992.699441 4498682.885472 0.100000
568738.099488 4499368.184928 0.600000
568029.798936 4499762.584742 0.600000
567669.099638 4500684.485496 -0.200000
```

I would like to add between the 2nd and 3rd 2 columns of null values. I would like also to add null values at the end (2 columns) and as last column a whole column with 0.100000

The result should be

```
568234.099421 4497975.785405 NULL NULL 0.000000 NULL NULL 0.100000
567992.699441 4498682.885472 NULL NULL 0.100000 NULL NULL 0.100000
568738.099488 4499368.184928 NULL NULL 0.600000 NULL NULL 0.100000
568029.798936 4499762.584742 NULL NULL 0.600000 NULL NULL 0.100000
567669.099638 4500684.485496 NULL NULL -0.200000 NULL NULL 0.100000
```

I'm really a beginner and I don't know how to do in awk or sed.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Reading the first page or 2 of any awk book or a glance at any awk tutorial would teach you how to do that. Please attempt to solve the problem yourself and then ask if you need help.

Comment: A good reference for beginners (and I do go back there 80% of the time I use `awk` is https://vc.airvectors.net/tsawk_1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simplest form that would be:

```
$ awk '{print $1, $2, "NULL", "NULL", $3, "NULL", "NULL", "0.100000"}' file
568234.099421 4497975.785405 NULL NULL 0.000000 NULL NULL 0.100000
567992.699441 4498682.885472 NULL NULL 0.100000 NULL NULL 0.100000
568738.099488 4499368.184928 NULL NULL 0.600000 NULL NULL 0.100000
568029.798936 4499762.584742 NULL NULL 0.600000 NULL NULL 0.100000
567669.099638 4500684.485496 NULL NULL -0.200000 NULL NULL 0.100000
```